# Why is getchar() being skipped?

Tags: c, io, mingw, mingw32, getchar

This is my code below, which I was working on. The output is this:

```
Enter Nums: 20 4
OP: Which option was that?
```

The `op = getchar();` part is being entirely ignored. Why?

I'm using gcc 4.6.2 MinGW.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int add(int num1, int num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}

int subs(int num1, int num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
}

int mul(int num1, int num2) {
    return num1 * num2;
}

float div(int num1, int num2) {
    return (float)num1 / num2;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int num1, num2;
    char op;
    fprintf(stdout,"Enter Nums: ");
    scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
    fprintf(stdout, "OP: ");
    op = getchar();
    switch(op) {
    case '+':
        printf("%d",add(num1, num2));
        break;
    case '-':
        printf("%d", subs(num1,num2));
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("%d",mul(num1,num2));
        break;
    case '/':
        printf("%f",div(num1, num2));
        break;
    default:
        printf("Which option was that?\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
```

There is a newline character after this input and you need to ignore it

```
scanf("%d %d%*c",&num1,&num2);
```

or

```
while((c=getchar()) != '\n') && c != EOF);
```

Else the newline is picked up by the `getchar()`